# Document a typescript function with named parameters in a D.R.Y. way

Tags: typescript

I'm making a function that takes named parameters with defaults.

Here's the function in JS

```js
function makeCake(params) {
  const {
    sugarCups = 1,
    flourCups = 1.5,
    butterCups = 0.5,
    milkCups = 0.5,
    vanillaTsps = 2,
    bakingPoweredTsps: 1.5,
    eggs = 2,
  } = params;
  ...
}
```

AFAICT, this is how I have to turn it into documented typescript

```
/**
 * Makes a cake
 * @param params
 * @param params.sugarCups (default 1)
 * @param params.flourCups (default 1.5)
 * @param params.butterCups (default 0.5)
 * @param params.milkCups: (default 0.5)
 * @param params.vanillaTsps: (default 2)
 * @param params.bakingPoweredTsps: (default 1.5)
 * @param params.eggs: (default 2)
 */
function makeCake(params: {
    sugarCups?: number,
    flourCups?: number,
    butterCups?: number,
    milkCups?: number,
    vanillaTsps?: number,
    bakingPoweredTsps?: number,
    eggs?: number,
} = {}) {
  const {
    sugarCups = 1,
    flourCups = 1.5,
    butterCups = 0.5,
    milkCups = 0.5,
    vanillaTsps = 2,
    bakingPoweredTsps = 1.5,
    eggs = 2,
  } = params;
  ...
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhZBDA1gUwM6XpAxk5UYACADvAE7wC2kJ5Fq+kxZl1zdAdKgK4DmZAwlyLoAFABNkAM3hcANgBdIARgCUDJrVa1U7SbID2XUoOGRxUmQuXsArGuiMaLJxwBGXefOTGhoidLlFAAZbe0IXLUodCgBLWUQTVAAuM39LYND1CJcdADd4ADs42XgAFVRhFPMAqwAmMMc2SLckGIKeAAV9AHdvZDFyytSLQOs7LKac9mQeHmThmsV6-GBwSS4CrHkY-QLIClx+XBEclIBvKEgr7j4fYQB+FIKuCldvABpLq71DO9RHyDPV4fL6QdyebyJAFAt6kT5XK6xeJQp4vWHwhH5IqyEqDf6o4Fw0GuVrtLq9Uj9PHQtEghGQGZzGmEz4AX0gAF5IGdWSpuZcsLtUIoLvSbgJfJzlBjvgYjIkpUpbDKwR4vH8pSEbCqkQlJVytSqscUyhV0FzaiqSYg2p0en0BmbFcrQYzzZBLZd2VycgBuS6U+RGPYAchD-tZQA)

This is very [W.E.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)(write every time). I had to specify every parameter 3 times, I had to specify the types twice, and I had to specify the defaults twice (it already knows the types based on their defaults). That's a lot of "write every time" instead of D.R.Y. (don't repeat yourself)

Is there some way to not have to repeat myself so much?

Even pulling the type out seems to be just as or even more verbose. Like I can make a `kCakeDefaults` and then use `Partial<typeof kCakeDefaults>` to not have to repeat the types but the actual amount of code is even larger and I'm still having to repeat myself to document the defaults

```
const kCakeDefaults = {
  sugarCups: 1,
  flourCups: 1.5,
  butterCups: 0.5,
  milkCups: 0.5,
  vanillaTsps: 2,
  bakingPoweredTsps: 1.5,
  eggs: 2,
};

/**
 * Makes a cake
 * @param params
 * @param params.sugarCups (default 1)
 * @param params.flourCups (default 1.5)
 * @param params.butterCups (default 0.5)
 * @param params.milkCups: (default 0.5)
 * @param params.vanillaTsps: (default 2)
 * @param params.bakingPoweredTsps: (default 1.5)
 * @param params.eggs: (default 2)
 */
function makeCake(params: Partial<typeof kCakeDefaults> = {}) {
  const {
    sugarCups,
    flourCups,
    butterCups,
    milkCups,
    vanillaTsps,
    bakingPoweredTsps,
    eggs,
  } = {
    ...kCakeDefaults,
    ...params,
  };
  return sugarCups + flourCups + butterCups + milkCups + vanillaTsps + bakingPoweredTsps + eggs;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-DXUiUfbi96UgkgA)

Is there a way to stop having to repeat things so much?

Answer (score 1):

You can spread the `params` object within the argument list. Your IDE should be able to infer the types from default value.

```
/**
 * Makes a cake
 * @param params
 * @param params.sugarCups (default 1)
 * @param params.flourCups (default 1.5)
 * @param params.butterCups (default 0.5)
 * @param params.milkCups: (default 0.5)
 * @param params.vanillaTsps: (default 2)
 * @param params.bakingPoweredTsps: (default 1.5)
 * @param params.eggs: (default 2)
 */
function makeCake({
  sugarCups = 1,
  flourCups = 1.5,
  butterCups = 0.5,
  milkCups = 0.5,
  vanillaTsps = 2,
  bakingPoweredTsps = 1.5,
  eggs = 2,
} = {}) {
  return sugarCups + flourCups + butterCups + milkCups + vanillaTsps + bakingPoweredTsps + eggs;
}
```